# How to print each elements of a hash map list using map function in clojure?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I am constructing a list of hash maps which is then passed to another function. When I try to print each hash maps from the list using `map` it is not working. I am able to print the full list or get the first element etc.

```
(defn m [a]
    (println a)
    (map #(println %) a))
```

The following works from the repl only.

```
(m (map #(hash-map :a %) [1 2 3]))
```

But from the program that I load using `load-file` it is not working. I am seeing the `a` but not its individual elements. What's wrong?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you demonstrate with small code example?

Comment: Some times it prints the result, other times it gives just nil. `doall` is working.

Comment: `(map #(println %) a)` is just `(map println a)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Clojure tranform functions return a lazy sequence. So, `(map #(println %) a)` return a lazy sequence. When consumed, the map action is applied and only then the print-side effect is visible.

If the purpose of the function is to have a side effect, like printing, you need to eagerly evaluate the transformation. The functions [dorun](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) and [doall](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall)

```
(def a [1 2 3])
(dorun (map #(println %) a))
; returns nil

(doall (map #(println %) a))
; returns the collection
```

If you actually don't want to map, but only have a side effect, you can use [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq). It is intended to 'iterate' to do side effects:

```
(def a [1 2 3])
(doseq [i a]
   (println i))
```

Comment: Note that you can also use the function `mapv` which is not lazy and always returns its result in a vector.

Comment: `println` returns `nil`, so you want `dorun`, not `doall`.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is simply to call an existing function on every item in a collection in order, ignoring the returned values, then you should use [`run!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!):

```
(run! println [1 2 3])
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;;=> nil
```

In some more complicated cases it may be preferable to use [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) as @Gamlor suggests, but in this case, `doseq` only adds boilerplate.

Comment: No, I need the value back.

Comment: @kadaj Then why did you accept Gamlor's answer? His `dorun` and `doseq` solutions return `nil` just like my `run!` solution, and his `doall` solution simply returns a sequence of `nil` values, which I can't imagine would be useful. Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: The code in the question was a sample. I am calling a function which returns a list of futures. Then when I apply `(map deref xs)` it was not working, but `(doall (map deref xs))` works.

Comment: @kadaj If your question really has nothing to do with printing, then the title of your question ("How to print each elements of a hash map using map function in clojure?") is incorrect, and you should edit your question's title and code to reflect what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I also wanted to know why printing was not working. So I posted this way. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use tail recursion:

```
(defn printList [a]
  (let [head (first a)
        tail (rest a)]
    (when (not (nil? head))
      (println head)
      (printList tail))))
```