# How to print map key/values with the values quoted?

Tags: clojure

normally when you print a map, the values are unquoted.

`(print {:abc "0" :def "1"})` results in `{:abc 0 :def 1}`.   I would like the output to look like `{:abc "0" :def "1"}`

I attempted to use the map function to get at every key-value pair and that did not work.

This was my attempt:

```
(defn print-map [m]
  (print "{")
  (map #((print (first %) "\"" (second %) "\",")) m)
  (print "}\n")
  )
```

nothing from the map gets printed

Comment: The reason nothing is printed is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39910297.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `pr`/`prn` instead of `print`/`println`, since they generate the string that could be read back by reader, meaning the strings would be quoted:

```
user=> (prn {:a "10" :b 20 :c "21"})
{:a "10", :b 20, :c "21"}
nil
```

Comment: ah, this is perfect - I did want to print something that would go back into the reader.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(print (str {:a "82834"}))
;{:a "82834"}
=> nil
```

Comment: @marathon Probably because it's inferior to using the standard function, as in [@leetwinski's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41527286/1562315). No problem :)

Comment: `str` might work for strings here, but `pr` is used to write things out, that are (most likely) readable back in. e.g. `(str (java.util.Date.))` vs `(pr (java.util.Date.))`